# Grid View Tutorial, Invoking on Null Object

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Java and Android Studio.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), trying to get a grid to work.

I created a new barebones app.

I followed the tutorial but I was getting an error in the following block.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

At this point, I was getting an error, saying that

```
? android.widget.adapterview.OnItemClickListener? (multiple choices)
```

at which point I selected the first one and translated it to

```
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

and the error went away.

I had no other issues with the tutorial until I attempted to run it.  I got the following error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter
 (android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.shiftedrec.myandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
```

Line 24 refers to this:

```
 gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

So my assumption right now is that `(this)` is null.  That gets passed from here:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

What about this is null, and how do I fix the error?  Thanks for bearing with me.

**Update**
I'll post the xml

activity_main.xml

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager is a better option in my opinion than GridView. Give it  a try. Its really easy to implement and manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` next to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 0):

`gridView` is the null Object, `R.id.gridview` might be an incorrect id. Check your XML layout file.

Explanation: `this` cannot be `null` as `onCreate` can only be invoked on an Object instance. Also, if `this` were null, the Exception would have been thrown somewhere within the `ImageAdapter` class.

Edit: as [Andro Selva pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079680/2427585) the id was correct but you forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: Andro Selva is correct. The GridView was not found because you forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Everything else I said is still correct, I'll edit my answer.